# Set Value of an Array at Index via reflection (not Property)

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, indexing

I want to set the Value of an Array of a class

```
 obj[]
```

via reflection!

e.g.

```
 obj[2] = aa;
```

How can I do this via Reflection in CSharp? I can do it for indexed Properties easily, but not for Array Types!

Comment: Well what do you have so far? What would the method signature look like for the method you want to write? Your question is unclear at the moment. (`Array.SetValue` perhaps?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are asking, but assuming you have a class something like this:

```
public class Blah
{
    public int[] Stuff;
}
```

Then this should work:

```
//some setup
var obj = new Blah();
obj.Stuff = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Get the field you want to manipulate:

```
var field = obj
    .GetType()
    .GetFields()
    .Single(f => f.Name == "Stuff");
```

Now you can get the value, then use `Array.SetValue` to change an element:

```
var theArray = (Array)field.GetValue(obj);
//Set element 1 to 100
theArray.SetValue(100, 1);
```

Comment: Array.SetValue was the Function I was looking for!